# Font-Family displays Issue right after reload

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the additional css option of WordPress to change the font-family of an anchor `<a>`. It's a custom uploaded font, using the Custom Fonts Plugin from Brainstorm Force. On initial load of the page, the custom css doesn't work and the default font-family is displayed. After reloading the page, and not closing it completely, the right font-family is displayed.

The font-family is `'Spring LP'`

Re-positioning the `font-family="Spring LP";` to the end of the css.
Using already implemented font-families seems to work without a problem.

```css
a.logo_link {
  color: #5F2417 !important;
  font-family: 'Spring LP' !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo pull-left">
  <h1 class="logo_h logo_h__txt">
    <a href="https://imkerei.k-evolution.de/" title="Wir haben den Honig für Ihren Geschmack!" class="logo_link">Imkerei Tietjen</a>
  </h1>
  <p class="logo_tagline">Wir haben den Honig für Ihren Geschmack!</p><!-- Site Tagline -->
</div>
```

The `!important` isn't even necessary, but even without it I still get the outcome of having to refresh the website once, before the font-family changes.

Comment: How are you loading the font-family into the browser before you call it in the CSS? Also it can be good to use fallbacks just encase the font does not load properly

Comment: Wow, your comment just gave me the right hint to fix it myself. Don't know if it was intended or not. The Plugin has the option 'Font Display' which has to be set to auto. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugin has the option 'Font Display' which has to be set to auto. It works now

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to define those parameters for the different states of a link, like:

```
a.logo_link:link, a.logo_link:visited {
  color: #5F2417 !important;
  font-family: 'Spring LP' !important;
}
```

and probably also for `a.logo_link:hover, a.logo_link:active`, but I suppose with a different color or something else that differes from the not-hovered or not-active state.